# htaccess folder protection + php7.0-fpm/fastcgi : .php files still accessible

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, fastcgi

I've setup a small droplet with php7.0-fpm/fastcgi, apache 2.4 on a Ubuntu 14.04.
Everything runs smoothly, except one small detail :

The thing is I want to protect a folder via a classic .htaccess protection, nothing fancy.

But, if I go to *"my-droplet-ip/my-protected-folder/my-file.php"*, I still can access it, even with an htaccess configured.

If I go to *"my-droplet-ip/my-protected-folder"*, the login/pass prompt shows up like expected. 
Same normal behavior for *"my-droplet-ip/my-protected-folder/a-file.(html|png|ini...)"*

I've read many things, like the fact that fastcgi could "process" php files before htaccess, but I can't really figure why/how.

Any idea?

Comment: where is your droplet configured? which cloud provider?

Comment: It's on DigitalOcean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eureka.

Short story, don't use :

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/var/www/html/$1
```

to handle php files with FastCGI, because it seems that `ProxyPassMatch` directives are evaluated before the `.htaccess`.

Better use :

```
<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000"
</FilesMatch>
```

More details over there : https://ma.ttias.be/apache-2-4-proxypass-for-php-taking-precedence-over-filesfilesmatch-in-htaccess/